# What is the difference among since, ever since and ever since then?

Tags: word-usage

The big clock has been silent ever since.

Can I delete since from the sentence above or add then after since?

And what is the difference among them?

Comment: You can "delete" ***then*** (or equivalents such as ***that time***) after ***since*** in such contexts, ***or*** you can discard ***ever***, but it's not very idiomatic to discard both. Note that you can't discard the actual word ***since***. Interestingly, I think we rarely include ***ever*** in *negating* contexts, so it wouldn't normally be included in, say, *The bell **hasn't** rung since then.* I can't explain why that's the case, but I'm pretty sure the principle is usually observed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I have seen forms simialr to "*The bell hasn't ever rung since then.*" when the intent is to strongly emphasize the finality of the cessation of ringing.  And when the intent is to deny that an event ever happened, as in "*I haven't ever been to Paris*" the word "ever" is usually included. But that isn't a "since" form. "*I haven't ever been to Paris since my marriage*" is possible, but usually "ever" would not be included in such a sentence.

Comment: @David: Maybe it's just that in negating contexts like that we usually say *I have **never** been to Paris since my marriage* anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> - The big clock has been silent ever since.
> - The big clock has been silent ever since then.
> - The big clock has been silent since then.
> - The big clock has been silent since that time.

These four sentences have essentially the same meaning. The version with "ever since then" emphasizes the time or event when the silence started more than the other forms do. The versions including "ever" imply that the silence is expected to be permanent. But these are very minor differences. None of these sentences makes much sense without some previous text indicating the moment or event which "then" refers to, the moment when the clock was first silent.

The question asks about omitting "since", which would leave:

> The big clock has been silent ever

This is not a complete grammatical sentence as it stands. To use a form without "since" one might write;

> The big clock was silent ever after.

This has much the same meaning as the "ever since then" form. But because "ever after" indicates a completed action, it is normally used with the simple past "was" rather than the "has been" form.

Comment: Can I omit ‘ever’ from those sentences?

Comment: @Y. zeng  Yes, i included "The big clock has been silent since then." as one of the valid forms. See also the comment by  FumbleFingers  on the question.

Comment: Can I say ‘The big clock was silent since’?

Comment: @Y. zeng Without context "*The big clock has been silent since*" is both meaningless and ungrammatical. It could be the second half of a sentence: "*The Queen died on June 15; the big clock has been silent since*"  or the second of two tightly coupled sentences, which allow an implied "then". And i think this form works better with "has been" than with "was".

Comment: The big clock was damaged many years ago and has been silent since.  Is this sentence right?

Comment: @Y. zeng  Yes that is grammatical. There is an implied 'then". You could also use "ever since", "since then" or "ever since then"